# How to hide html elements in mobile mode only

Tags: website-design, html

I'm working with the following code on my squarepace Pacific template via the html code injection (the code creates a white double lined border around the page):

```
<head>
<style>
body {
  margin:0px;
  background-image: url(http://static1.squarespace.com/static/56df76e4356fb0e00c7e94da/t/5703667a27d4bdaccf43195e/1459840646163/paper_box_texture+CMYK.jpg);
} 
.top, .left, .right, .bottom {
display: block;
position: absolute;
width:100%;
height:180%;
}   
.top  {
border-top: 1em double #fff; top: 40px; z-index:100;
}
.left {
border-left: 1em double #fff; left: 40px; z-index:200;
}
.right {
border-right: 1em double #fff; right: 40px; z-index:300;
}
.bottom {
border-bottom: 1em none #fff; bottom: 200px; z-index:400;
}           
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

It works on the desktop mode but for mobile it cuts off the copy:

[image: Mobile View]

Does anyone know how to enable this border on desktop but remove it for mobile device?

Thanks!

Comment: https://answers.squarespace.com/questions/18706/hide-a-text-block-on-mobile-devices.html

Comment: Hi Lauren, don't forget to accept an answer if it is satisfactory! This prevents questions showing up in the list of unanswered questions and helps everyone out with a bit of 'rep' :)

Comment: It's easier for you to use a one of the html CSS Javascript framework Like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: Couldn't you just add more padding to the copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS to not display these divs below a particular break point. *(I use 400px in the example below, but you can set that to whatever you want.)*

```
@media screen and (max-width: 25rem) { /* 400 px */

  .top, .left, .right, .bottom {
    display: none;
  }

}
```